# How to change time in DBEdit bounded to DateTime Field to military time format like ' 2300'?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe3

I'm using Delphi XE3 and XE2

I have a TDBEdit which is bounded to a TDateTime field in my database.
My TDBEdit should display the time in military format which is 2300
but it's currently displaying the regular time 10:05:00 AM

I've tried to set the input mask to something like !9000 but it gave me: 00 AM
I've checked all possible ways with the input mask with no use.

Is there anyway to get over that ?

**Also I cannot see the Data.DB.TDateTimeField.DisplayFormat property anywhere**

[image: screen 01]

**Not here either**

[image: screen 02]

Comment: 1) TDateTimeField.DisplayFormat exists - just check in the source. You cannot see it because you reference the class and not an instance. 2) FieldByName returns a TField and not a TDateTimeField.

Comment: Your final try (the one that's like my answer) is missing a closing parenthesis before the `.`. It should be `TDateField(Center_Table.FieldByName('Report_DateTime')).Dis` - see the `)).`? My answer is correct, as the images I posted with it show.

Comment: I know It's there but It doesn't appear to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't see them because you're trying to do it wrong, as Uwe said.

Create a persistent field (double click your table or query, and add a field for the TDateTime field), and then use it in your code. Here's one for a plain `TTable` (actually a `TADSTable` from Advantage Database) with a `TDateTimeField` called `DATE_OPEN`:

[image: DisplayFormat property image]

If you don't want to create persistent fields, you can always just typecast (make sure it's an actual `TDateField` if you do so, or you'll end up with an access violation). Also note that there are two `)` characters before the dot `.`. The left one closes the `FieldByName` function call, the second completes the typecast to `TDateField`, and both have to be there in order for this to work.

[image]

You can then set the `DisplayFormat` to `hhnn` to accept times like `0900` or `2100` for 9:00 AM or 9:00 PM respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The correct entry for the fields DisplayFormat property is "hhnn".

Comment: umm.. There is no Fields DisplayFormat property here or anywhere not on the DBEdit, DateTime Field or Dataset

Comment: @MS his talking about http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DB.TDateTimeField.DisplayFormat

Comment: See the image, I couldn't find this property anywhere, how can I unlock it man !!